# GeoFire and Firebase - How to query for a specified number of nearest-by entries?

Tags: gps, location, firebase, geofire

My app is using a Firebase and I am looking at Geofire for assistance with location querying. Instead of querying for all entries within a specified radius, I would like to perform a query for retrieving the x closest entries in location to the coordinates I provide. Is there a way to efficiently do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not a feature of GeoFire (at least not that I'm aware off). Keep in mind that Firebase mostly deals with data that changes in realtime. So those x closest items might change all the time.

Comment: Like Frank said, not directly with GeoFire. An easy way to do it would be to start the query with a small radius, and increase the radius until you reach >=x keys. You can store those keys in an object sorted by distance, since GeoFire `key_entered` returns the distance from the center of the query. But if you're working with a large dataset, you're going to need to get fancy with the data structures you use to store the objects.

Comment: Thank you both! Sinan, can you clarify what you mean when you say I will need to get fancy storing them? I was under the impression I would only need to get fancy retrieving the information since GeoFire is already clever about how it stores location information.

Comment: I'll do my best. So since you're aiming for >= x keys, you'll need a way to sort the keys that you get back in order to only display the exact x closest keys. So i'd run the multi-part query, and then store the resultant keys in a factory sorted by distance to the center of the query, and then you can insert new keys as needed. I was originally thinking of crazy things like using linked lists and polar coordinates as md5 hashes but you're probably better off using underscore.js to insert new keys in an array.